# Jquery sheet facing rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html-rendering

jquery sheet rendering issue in chrome and it is working fine on Mozilla Firefox, I am using sheet version "jQuery.Sheet v3.1 Release Candidate"
http://code.google.com/p/jquerysheet/

I want to make the rendering faster in chrome it was already working fine in mozilla firefox, is it possible to achieve using jquery sheet version.
"jQuery.Sheet v3.1 Release Candidate"
http://code.google.com/p/jquerysheet/

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+sheet+chrome+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.